# Click on the Notification programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, accessibilityservice

I trying click on the notification after receiving it.

I'm able to drag the notification drawer using the Accessibility service.

For clicking the notification I'm using `accessibilityEvent.getSource()` and 
   `accessibilityNodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);`

My code:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

/**
 * On receiving the AccessibilityEvent performs the Actions
 *
 * @param event
 */
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Get the Accessibility Event");
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END) {
        handleTypeTouchInteractionEndEvents(event);
    }
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        handleTypeWindowStateChangedEvents(event);
    }
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo accessibilityServiceInfo = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    accessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED |
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.CAPABILITY_CAN_PERFORM_GESTURES;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT | AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.notificationTimeout = NOTIFICATION_TIME_OUT;
    this.setServiceInfo(accessibilityServiceInfo);
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    //Do Nothing
}

/**
 * Performs the action for TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END events
 *
 * @param accessibilityEvent
 */
private void handleTypeTouchInteractionEndEvents(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    switch (accessibilityEvent.getAction()) {
        case EXPAND_NOTIFICATIONS_DRAWER:
            Log.i(TAG, "perfroming expand notification bar");         performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS);
            break;
        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "Event type not defined");
    }
}

private void handleTypeWindowStateChangedEvents(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    switch (accessibilityEvent.getAction()) {
        case ACTION_CLICK:
            Log.i(TAG, "Performing click Action");
            findNotificationIconAndClick("com.my.app:id/notification_icon", accessibilityEvent);
            Log.i(TAG, "Click Action is successfull");
        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "Event type not defined");
    }
}


public void findNotificationIconAndClick(String id, AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo accessibilityNodeInfo = accessibilityEvent.getSource();
    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodeInfoList = accessibilityNodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id);
    if (nodeInfoList != null && !nodeInfoList.isEmpty()) {
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo : nodeInfoList) {
            if (nodeInfo != null) {
                performClick(nodeInfo);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm new to using accessibility service. Can someone tell me if there is any mistake from my side or if it is not possible to click on a notification using accessibility service? Are there any other possibilities without using Accessibility Service to click on the Notification?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to click on the notification, you have to extend the NotificationListenerService, implement what have to be implemented then you can call `sbn.getNotification().contentIntent.send()`. This way is like if user was clicking on the notification from the notification tray.

Answer (score 1):

Not all accessibility events will return a source. In fact, most (or at least the events that occur most frequently) do not. Make sure you're limiting to a reasonable subset of events in your configuration AND/OR doing a null check on `event.getSource()`.

Comment: Is there any other possible way to click on the notification

Comment: No, there is no "Just select this notification" option. Simulating the click event on it is your only option.